# Error when sending an email with subject using newsapi.org API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send an email with a subject using the newsapi.org API. However, when I include the subject in my email, I encounter the following error:

*smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'5.7.1 This message is not RFC 5322 compliant. There are multiple Subject\n5.7.1 headers. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has\n5.7.1 been blocked. Please visit\n5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant and review\n5.7.1 RFC 5322 specifications for more information. n17-20020a05640204d100b00533dd4d2947sm1005628edw.74 - gsmtp')*

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from send_email import send_email

topic = "tesla"

api_key = "-"
url = ("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?"
       f"q={topic}&"
       "from=2023-09-05&"
       "sortBy=publishedAt&"
       "apiKey=-&"
       "language=en")

request = requests.get(url)

content = request.json()

body = ""
for article in content["articles"][:20]:
    if article["title"] is not None:
        body = ("Subject: Today's news"
                + "\n" + body + article["title"]
                + "\n" + article["description"]
                + "\n" + article["url"] + 2*"\n")

body = body.encode("utf-8")
send_email(message=body)
```

I want to send an email with a subject, but if I change the body to include the  email address as follows:

```
body = ("From: email@email.com"
                "Subject: Today's news"
                + "\n" + body + article["title"]
                + "\n" + article["description"]
                + "\n" + article["url"] + 2*"\n")
```

The email is sent without the subject, and no error occurs. How can I resolve this issue and include the subject in the email correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the loop executes the first time, `body` is a long string beginning with "Subject:".

When it executes the second time, `body` is assigned to a new long string beginning with "Subject"... but it *also* includes its original contents, so now it has "Subject" twice.

And then three times, and four times... until the loop finally ends.

You should assign the subject only once, outside of the loop, and you shouldn't re-assign body to repeat its contents:

```
body = "Subject: Today's news\n\n"
for article in content["articles"][:20]:
    if article["title"] is not None:
        body += article["title"]
        body += "\n"
        body += article["description"]
        body += "\n"
        body += article["url"]
        body += "\n\n"
```